# WorkManager NetworkType with "OR" condition

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I've just finished a codelab about [`WorkManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html) and I was wondering how to get a "OR" condition with it. After checking the `setRequiredNetworkType` I see it only accepts one argument of `NetworkType` type.

```kotlin
/**
 * Sets whether device should have a particular {@link NetworkType} for the
 * {@link WorkRequest} to run.  The default value is {@link NetworkType#NOT_REQUIRED}.
 *
 * @param networkType The type of network required for the work to run
 * @return The current {@link Builder}
 */
public @NonNull Builder setRequiredNetworkType(@NonNull NetworkType networkType) {
    this.mRequiredNetworkType = networkType;
    return this;
}
```

For example, I'd like that my task runs when `NetworkType.UNMETERED` or `NetworkType.CONNECTED`. is it possible ?

---

EDIT: Maybe that wasn't a good example, I wanted to know if it's possible have an `OR` condition to use for `Constraint`.

Comment: I suspect that `UNMETERED` is a sub-type of `CONNECTED`. So, in your case, you may be able to just request `CONNECTED`.

Comment: I think UNMETERED will indicate a connected unmetered network. I would suggest to use  UNMETERED for your use case

Comment: @CommonsWare I've updated my post to add details, it seems I wasn't really clear, my bad

Comment: "I wanted to know if it's possible have an OR condition to use for Constraint." -- not in a single piece of work. You might be able to rig up multiple pieces of work with separate constraints, and try some coordination such that only one will be used.

Comment: Can you add in a post so I accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CommonsWare answered my queestion in the comment:

> "I wanted to know if it's possible have an OR condition to use for Constraint." -- not in a single piece of work. You might be able to rig up multiple pieces of work with separate constraints, and try some coordination such that only one will be used

Answer (score 0):

> connected - Any working network connection is required for this work.
>
> metered - A metered network connection is required for this work.
>
> not_roaming - A non-roaming network connection is required for this
>   work.
>
> unmetered - An unmetered network connection is required for this work.

Based on the above and based on your use case, you can use UNMETERED which will indicate both - Connected and Unmetered